# PHP nested for loop skipping every 2nd number

Tags: php

I am trying to get 2 simple for loops. The first for loop cycles through results from the database. The 2nd for loop prints out a table for each store based on the amount of weeks selected.

My code looks as follows

```
$retval     =   f_select_query($query_select_stores, $datarows);

$rowcount   =  count($datarows);

for ($counter = 0; $counter< $rowcount; $counter++) {
    $store_name = $datarows[$counter]->store_name;
    echo '<table style="width: 100%; border:1px solid black;">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $store_name . '</th>';
        
    for ($i=$week_number_start; $i<=$week_number_end; $i++){
        echo '<th style="border: 1px solid black;>Week ' . $i . '</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
}
```

And where the result is printed out, I get Week 2, Week 4, Week 6 and so on. Pretty much every 2nd week. Why is it doing that? I'm probably missing something very simple..

Comment: what is the value of $week_number_start ?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly? That would happen if you used `$i++` in the `echo` line.

Comment: Because then you're incrementing `$i` twice: once in the `for()` line, and again in the `echo` line.

Comment: @GNassro The value of $week_number_start is 1 and $week_number_end is 30.

Comment: @Barmar How am I incrementing the value if $i in the echo line? I'm not using $i++ in there?

Comment: PS `f_select_query()` is not Vanilla PHP so we also have no idea what that does

Comment: i think it's a design error, maybe some tag is missing or something else, and you have  double quote missing to close the style attribute in the seconde for loop

Comment: The missing double quote is clearly the problem. It's combining two `<th>` elements.

Comment: @Barmar that was exactly it. Now I feel stupid... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have double quote missing in the seconde for loop, as Barmar mentionned, it's combining two  elements.
so try this after add the missing double quote:

```
$retval     =   f_select_query($query_select_stores, $datarows);

$rowcount   =  count($datarows);

for ($counter = 0; $counter< $rowcount; $counter++) {
    $store_name = $datarows[$counter]->store_name;
    echo '<table style="width: 100%; border:1px solid black;">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $store_name . '</th>';
        
    for ($i=$week_number_start; $i<=$week_number_end; $i++){
        echo '<th style="border: 1px solid black;">Week ' . $i . '</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
}
```